# UV Warp distance units in blender 2.92 not scaling correctly

Tags: uv, units

Using blender 2.92, I have my scene units set to:

- Unit System: Metric
- Unit Scale: 1.0000
- Length: Centimeters

Then I have imported a lego man who is about 5cm and dimensions in "Item" panel show correctly.

I have setup a UV map of mouths for my man, as per this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NlvgMYZgaY&t=1370s

This works correctly until I try using a UV Warp to move the position of the map around using the distance between 2 bones.

In the UV Warp blender docs it says that moving the distance between two bones by 1 unit (ie 1cm in my case) will move warp the UV map by 1 full UV space.  So moving the bones 0.5cm apart should warp the map half way across the UV space.

However this does not happen, instead I have to move the bones really far apart, about 1000cm, to warp the UV map by 1 unit.

How can I get it work as per the documentation?

*Note that I've tried changing the "Unit Scale", for example to 0.01, but then the dimensions of my lego man are incorrectly reported.*

Comment: I think you're mistaken that 1 unit = 1 cm in this case.  In this case, 1 unit  = 1m, regardless of what units Blender is displaying to you in fields.  (And it should be 100cm you have to move in world space to change UV by 1.0.)  If you want the UV warp to act 100 times more powerfully, without changing any of your scales, then you should create a new (empty) control, and use it to control your UV warp's "to" marker via scripted expression drivers to echo motion of the new control, just one hundred (or one thousand) fold.

Comment: So how do I change the actual units to 1unit = 1cm if my above settings did not do that?